# Qt Crash with QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat();

Tags: qt, opengl, video, try-catch, textures

I want to display a video texture in a QGraphicsScene which has a QGLWidget viewport.

I read the video with openCV, I grab each frame, convert it to QImage and then I do :

```
QImage img=QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(videoFrame);//videoFrame is the frame got from openCV video reading and converted to QImage
```

My problem is that it works well with a lot of videos (I use .mp4) but with others (still .mp4), that line of code makes my application crash, and I can't found out why.

My question is how to prevent that crash without knowing the exact cause? I tried with :

```
QImage img;
try{
    img=QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(videoFrame);
}
catch(...)
{
    img=QImage("defaultImg.jpg");
}
```

but it still crashes at

```
img=QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(videoFrame);
```

and the catch part is not executed.

EDIT : 
I get the image with that :

```
QImage VideoPlayer::getVideoFrame()
{
    IplImage* frame= cvQueryFrame( capture );
    m=cv::Mat(frame);//m is a member of class VideoPlayer

    return cvMatToQImage(m);
}

QImage VideoPlayer::cvMatToQImage(cv::Mat inMat)
{
    cv::Mat temp;
    cv::cvtColor(inMat, temp,CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage cvMatToQImg((uchar*) temp.data, temp.cols, temp.rows, temp.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    return QImage(cvMatToQImg);
}
```

And in my QgraphicsScene subclass :

```
QImage videoFrame = videoPlayerInstance->getVideoFrame();
QImage img=QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(videoFrame);//crashes here
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, img.width(), img.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.bits());
```

Qt doc says :

> QImage QGLWidget::​convertToGLFormat(const QImage & img) Converts the
>   image img into the unnamed format expected by OpenGL functions such as
>   glTexImage2D(). The returned image is not usable as a QImage, but
>   QImage::width(), QImage::height() and QImage::bits() may be used with
>   OpenGL. The GL format used is GL_RGBA.

And indeed, since width(), height() and bits() are used in glTexImage2D. And I get and can output them from videoFrame without problem and crash.
And again, it works with some .mp4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt code does not throw exceptions, so the `try...catch` block is superfluous. It crashes because `videoFrame` is null or points to deallocated data or somesuch. That's where the problem is. That `convertToGLFormat` crashes is a symptom of passing it a junk image.

Specifically, the `QImage` constructor that you're using in `cvMatToQImage` is constructing an image that uses a temporary buffer. The documentation of the constructor states:

> The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage and all copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the original buffer.

You should force the image to retain the matrix. You can probably also not prematurely pessimize by forcing a copy of the matrix argument - pass a const reference instead.

```
static void cvMatQImageCleanup(void *info) {
  delete reinterpret_cast<cv::Mat*>(info);
}

QImage VideoPlayer::cvMatToQImage(const cv::Mat & inMat)
{
    auto temp = new cv::Mat;
    cv::cvtColor(inMat, *temp, CV_BGR2RGB);
    return QImage((uchar*) temp->data, temp->cols, temp->rows, temp->step, 
      QImage::Format_RGB888, &cvMatQImageCleanup, temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much !! What is your static function made for? I am not good enough at C++ to understand that :) .

Comment: @SteveTJS `static` means that the function is local to the translation unit. It's a C-ism, but still has place in C++. You could use an anonymous namespace if you wished so, but it's a bit more verbose.